# How can I retrieve multiple elements from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml that's returned when I do an export of TableStorage data using the Clumsy Leaf Table explorer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://x.table.core.windows.net/" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">TestContents</title>
    <updated />
    <link rel="self" title="TestContents" href="TestContents" />

    <entry>
        <title type="text" />
        <updated />
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit"  />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>010100A</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:Title>ssq</d:Title>
                <d:Type>1</d:Type>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title type="text" />
        <updated />
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit"  />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>010100B</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:Title>yy</d:Title>
                <d:Type>1</d:Type>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title type="text" />
        <updated />
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit" />
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>010100C</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:Title>xx</d:Title>
                <d:Type>1</d:Type>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I am using the following code:

```
XNamespace a = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
XElement feed = XElement.Load(@"c:\data\contents.xml");
var titles =
    from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
    let partitionKey = entry.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
    let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
    let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
    let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")

    select title;

foreach (var title in titles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(title.Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

To get data from an XML file.  The code works perfectly and gives me the value of all the
elements:

`<d:Title>xxx</d:Title>`

I would now like to get the value of the partitionKey also. To do this I modified the line

```
select title:
```

to

```
select partitionKey, title;
```

However this gives me an error:

"A local variable named 'title' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'title' which is already used in a child scope to denote something else.

Can someone help and suggest how I could also get the values for partitionKey as well as title and display on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an anonymous type:

```
XNamespace a = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
XElement feed = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var result =
    from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
    let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
    let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
    let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
    let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
    select new
    {
        Title = title.Value,
        PartitionKey = partitionKey.Value,
    };

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.Title, item.PartitionKey);
}
```

or if you intend to pass the result of this LINQ query outside of the current method start by defining a model:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}
```

and then project the LINQ query to an `IEnumerable<Result>`:

```
select new Result
{
    Title = title,
    PartitionKey = partitionKey
};
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have updated your answer and shown the XML you are dealing with it seems that PartitionKey is a subnode of `<m:properties>`, so why are you using `let partitionKey = entry.Element(d + "PartitionKey")`? In example `entry` represents the `<entry>` node. I have updated my previous code sample to match your XML. You should be more careful/consistent in your LINQ queries:

```
let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
```

Comment: I tried this but something unusual happens. d:Title is found in the namespace but PartitionKey is not. So it returns null for all the partition keys.

Comment: Well, maybe if you showed your XML file and explained what PartitionKeys is in your specific case we might be able to help. Right now you seem to be talking about some *PartitionKeys*, and you seem to be the only one aware of what that is. I hope you realize that we cannot read your mind, the XML file your are trying to parse and why your code doesn't work.

Comment: I will update the question with the XML. Sorry for my delaying in replying (terrible internet connection here) and also for not including that. Here's what I get returned in result: { Title = {<d:Title xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">Topics</d:Title>}, PartitionKey = null }

Comment: You are selecting PartitionKey from the entry node which obvious makes absolutely no sense, because `<d:PartitionKey>` is a subnode of `<m:properties>` whereas in your code you are using `let partitionKey = entry.Element(d + "PartitionKey")`, but entry is of course the `<entry>` node. You should be more consistent in your LINQ queries. I have updated my initial code sample to match your specific XML. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much Darin. I did not see that it was from the entry. My bad copy/paste. I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
select partitionKey, title;
```

does not do what you think it does. It looks like you want to return instances of an anonymous type with two properties: `partitionKey` and `title`. To do this, you must declare the anonymous type explicitly, i.e.

```
select new { partitionKey, title };
```

As to what your line of code actually does, based on the compiler error text, I think that it is simply illegal syntax.

NB: The VB.NET compiler is a bit more forgiving. It does treat `Select partitionKey, title` as syntactic sugar for `Select New With { partitionKey, title }`, which is what you would expect.